# Changing jquery version breaks anchors

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile

I'm just getting into learning flask so I have created a very simple page with a popup form.  What I can't understand is when using jquery 1.7.0 and above the popup form works, but the anchors linking back to different sections of the page do not.  If I change the jquery version to 1.6.4 and below, the anchor links work, but not the popup form.  This is also my first time using jquery mobile and could be part of my problem.  I have posted my code below.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks so much!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='css/style.css') }}">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>   
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/stripe-local.js') }}"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:700i|Titillium+Web" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=><a href="#home">Home</a></li>    
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pay">Pay</a></li>
            </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="jumbotron" id="home">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Design Something</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="about">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="anchor">About</h1>
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/img.jpg') }}" class="img-rounded center-block"></img>
            <div class="container">
            <p>blah blah blah blah blah</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="contact">
        <div class="row">
            <h1 class="anchor">Contact Me</h1>  
            <p>email@address.com</p>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="pay">
    <h1 class="anchor">Pay Now</h1>
    <a href="#popupPay" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all ui-icon-check ui-btn-icon-left">Pay Now</a>
        <div data-role="popup" id="popupPay" class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">       
            <form method="post" action="charge.py">
                <div>
                    <h3>Payment Form</h3>   
                    <label for="name" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name">
                    <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Pay $">
                    <div class="outcome">
                        <div class="error" role "alert"></div>
                        <div class="success">
                        Success! Your Stripe token is <span class="token"></span>   
                        </div>  
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but why are you changing jQuery libraries around?

Comment: Just trying to understand what's breaking and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anchor link breaks due to jquery mobile.
jQuery mobile has a feature which changes all the links to ajax call. 
For what purpose you are using jquery mobile? if you are using it only for particular function than instead of loading entire build load only feature which you want to use http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

or you can disable it by adding following code

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much!  I was using jQuery mobile for the pop-up form.   I'm still learning about jQuery mobile, but what is the purpose to change anchors to ajax calls?

Comment: This is to load site faster in mobile , so that every time user clicks any link page does not reloads completely.